# Ubuntu on AWS, su(switch user) command not works

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, sudo, su

I made a little mistake this morning.

I wanted to change the owner of the wordpress website directory, and I commanded as below.

```
sudo chown -vR :theuser / var/wwwwordpress/
```

But this command was wrong. This command changed all files of my system. ('/ var/' should be '/var/')

I was so confused, then stopped this task by 'Ctrl + z'.

But my root account already has been outed from sudo permission.

```
When I type 'sudo', system says 'sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?'
```

I thought the root has been changed to 'theuser'. So I tried to 'su' command, but it doesn't work.

```
su: Authentication failure
```

Password is correct, but I can't log on anymore.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you're on AWS, simply create a new instance & redeploy your code to the new instance.

EC2 instances should not be treated like traditional servers, and you should make sure that you can re-create your stack when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Run following command (as root user)

```
chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
```